# Addition of fractions in z11

Tags: ring-theory

compute 3/5+2/7+1/6 in Z11. Please give me a hint on how to go about it. I have created a table for Z11 but unsure of the next step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $\mathbb Z_{11}$ all elements except $0$ are invertible; in your table find the ones that yield $1$ after multiplication by $5,$ $7$ or $6$ respectively. Dividing in a field is just multiplying by the multiplicative inverse.